# Greeks for Pricing Convertible Bond Using Jump Diffusion Model

Tags: jump-diffusion

I'm learning the jump diffusion model used to price a convertible bond, and got the following stochastic differential equation under risk neutral measure:

$$dS = (r+\lambda*p)Sdt + \sigma*SdW+Sdq$$

$\lambda$ is intensity of default

$dq$ is a Poisson process used to model default

$p$ is stock prices drop amount upon default

Assume we have two cases:

1. stock price drops 30% upon default, $p$ is 30%
2. stock price drops 50% upon default, $p$ is 50%

I know the convertible bond price under the second assumption should be higher since its drift is higher, what about the Greeks between these two assumptions, the second assumption creates higher Greeks (Ex. delta)?